# How to change vector pathData programmatically

Tags: java, android, vector, android-vectordrawable

I want to add vectorDrawable to my google map, I have to change the vector pathData value when user touch on map, is there a way to change it? Or is there a way creating vector with pathData programmatically  ?

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">


<path

    android:name="path1"
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M9,2c-1.05,0 -2.05,0.16 -3,0.46 4.06,1.27 7,5.06 7,9.54 0,4.48 -2.94,8.27 -7,9.54 0.95,0.3 1.95,0.46 3,0.46 5.52,0 10,-4.48 10,-10S14.52,2 9,2z"/>
```

Comment: did you get answer for this problem?

Comment: there is no simple way to solve this problem